# What is the difference between those two requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2

For a task automatization I needed to write some python code, which makes post request to a web service, then retrieves information etc..

First I tried to use requests.

```
import requests

def make_invoice_body(terminal, service, code, number):
    return {
        "terminalId": terminal,
        "serviceId" : service,
        "invoiceNumber": number,
        "invoiceCode": code,
        "paymentType": 1,
        "requestNumber": random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
    }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
body = make_invoice_body(51, "1001000", "FOO", "123456")

requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

Above code piece was recieved error as a response.

Then I tried with `urllib2`,

```
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, body) #body from above
print resp.read()
```

and it worked.

Now I am curious about differences of above snippets. Shouldn't they do the same task and recieve equivalent answers?

Comment: What was the error received?

Comment: this, I believe is not much important  - as I am asking the difference between two post requests, but it is a customized internal server error if it will helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "native dict" format in HTTP world.

The real difference is that `requests` is too smart.

When using `data=` in `requests`, you are trying to post `multipart/form-data`. In this case, a `dict` will be unzipped into key-value pairs in `form-data` format.

When using `json=` in `requests`, `requests` will automatically `json.dumps` your `dict` into a raw byte string and set `Content-Type` for you.

But in `urllib`, it does nothing more than you give. You need to manually `json.dumps` your `dict`. So I believe the example you give is wrong. it should be like the following:

```
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(body)) #body from above
print resp.read()
```

Thanks for @t.m.adam's reminding.

Comment: Your explanation is very good except for the last line. The `data` parameter accepts string and if you pass a dict it will raise a TypeError. I'm confused by the op's claim that it works, but i suspect that they used `json.dumps` since json is imported. Perhaps i've missed something, if you could explain i'd be grateful. +1 regardless.

Comment: @t.m.adam Actually, I didn't test `urllib2` as it is definitely an outdated lib until you comment. And then I tested it, it shows it really only accepts string but not `dict`. The example given by OP is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. But i wouldn't say that `urllib` is _that_ bad. I use it sometimes (i prefer `requests` too) for compatibility reasons, and it's quite decent. When it comes to posting files it's a nightmare though.

Answer (score 3):

As of Requests version 2.4.2 and onwards you can use the json parameter inside the request as

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
```

If you use the json parameter, you can also remove the 'application/json' header because the json parameter makes it redundant.

If you want to use data, you need to first convert your dict to a json using

```
data = json.dumps(body)
```

Comment: well, putting `json=` instead `data=` fixes the problem, but can you please explain what is the difference?

Comment: So the difference is that urllib2 automatically converts the data to the JSON format required by the endpoint. 

Requests sends the data in the native dict format which the web backend can't understand